# codeigniter login form with ajax request on bootstrap modal return into error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to create make a login sistem based on codeigniter and bootstrap modal performing AJAX request.

so the problem is like this if i dont use the codeigniter validation class all is good but when i useit return me this errors:

POST localhost/site/login 500 (Internal Server Error) and
XHR finished loading: "localhost/site/login".

here is the js code:

```
var loginform = '<form id="lgfrm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">'+
    '<div id="rsp"></div>'+
  '<div class="form-group">'+
    '<label  class="col-sm-3 control-label">username</label>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-8">'+
      '<input type="text" name="user" class="form-control"  placeholder="username">'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="form-group">'+
    '<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-8">'+
      '<input type="password" name="psw" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password">'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="form-group">'+
    '<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8">'+
      '<div class="checkbox">'+
        '<label>'+
          '<input type="checkbox"> Remember me'+
        '</label>'+
      '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>';
'</form>'
    var customModal = '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">'+
      '<div class="modal-dialog">'+
        '<div class="modal-content">'+
          '<div class="modal-header">'+
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+
            '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="modal-body">'+
            loginform+
         ' </div>'+
          '<div class="modal-footer">'+
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="runlogin">Login</button>'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
      '</div>'+
    '</div>';

    $(function(){

        $('#login').click(function(){
            $('body').append(customModal);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#runlogin').click(function(){
                var dtf = $('#lgfrm').serialize();
                var request = $.ajax({
                  url: "site/login",
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType:"json",
                  data: dtf
                });

                request.done(function( msg ) {
                  $( "#rsp" ).html( msg );
                });

                request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });
            });
                $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

        });
    });
and here what i have on the controler class:
public function login(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'user','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('psw', 'psw','trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');  
        if($this->form_validation->run() !== false){
            echo json_encode('works');
        }else{
            if(validation_errors() != '') {
                echo validation_errors();//json_encode(validation_errors());
                }

            }
    }
```

Comment: have you tested login controller without ajax? Is htaccess set to not need `index.php` in path?

Comment: on htaccess i have like this  RewriteRule ^(site(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

Comment: so you don't use `index.php` in other url's? I don't read htaccess well. If that's not problem...did you try regular from to login controller? Also look in request itself in browser console, if working in development environment should get error detail sent back

Comment: @charlietfl  i tested without the validation end return the result on the bs model with out problems. ps: sorry for my bad english:)

Comment: but did you try using regular form, no ajax, and with validation rules

Comment: yes i tried but i dont know where i make wrong :(

Comment: 1) fix up your modal html to just be hidden on the page, not created via js  2) read through this to understand your ajax login and how to debug it http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/04/how-do-i-use-ajax-with-framework-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of debugging with firebug i found the problem! was because I did not create page form_validation_lang ! after i created everything goes well.Thanks to all